# Attach Snackbar to RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-layout

I am creating a typical chat application with a RecyclerView in the middle and the messaging controls at the bottom.

I would like to show a snackbar which is bound to the RecyclerView (and therefore shown at the bottom of the Recyclerview), so that it is shown above the messaging controls and not at the very bottom of the screen.

When i set `snackbarChat = Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.recycler_view), "", Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE);` the snackbar is still shown (and covering the messaging controls) at the bottom of the screen and not as intended at the bottom of the RecyclerView.

**Question:** How can i bin the snackbar to the screen of the Recyclerview?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the documentation for `make()`:

> Snackbar will try and find a parent view to hold Snackbar's view from the value given to `view`. Snackbar will walk up the view tree trying to find a suitable parent, which is defined as a `CoordinatorLayout` or the window decor's content view, whichever comes first.

So, when you pass the result of `findViewById(R.id.recycler_view)`, the `make()` call will look at the RecyclerView's parent, and the parent's parent, and so on... until it finds either a `CoordinatorLayout` or gets to the main content view.

I'm betting that you're running into the second half of that.

An easy way to fix would be to wrap your `RecyclerView` in a `CoordinatorLayout`. I can't say exactly how to do that without seeing your layout XML, but probably you just want

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    android:layout_width="whatever you had on the recyclerview"
    android:layout_height="whatever you had on the recyclerview"
    ...>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        .../>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```